# SQL query for RFM analysis with user segmentation

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with user_id, order_id, date and order amount.

I wrote a query that divides all users into quartiles using the NTILE function, and then I need to distribute the resulting quartiles into segments.

The upper part of the code works, the lower one is segmentation which I would like to implement, but unfortunately I can't manage to combine both codes.

```
WITH rfm_raw AS (

SELECT  
    user_id,
    DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(),MAX(created_at), DAY) AS R,
    COUNT(*) AS F,
    AVG(SUM) AS M
FROM `TABLE`
GROUP BY user_id
),

calc_r AS (
SELECT 
  user_id,
  R,
  NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY R ASC) R_S
FROM rfm_raw),

calc_f AS (
SELECT user_id,
F,
NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY F DESC) F_S
FROM rfm_raw),

calc_m AS (
SELECT user_id,
M,
NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY M DESC) M_S
FROM rfm_raw)

SELECT
calc_r.user_id,
R,
R_S,
F,
F_S,
M,
M_S
FROM calc_r
LEFT JOIN calc_f
ON calc_r.user_id = calc_f.user_id
LEFT JOIN calc_m
ON calc_r.user_id = calc_m.user_id
```

--

```
CASE 
WHEN (R_S = 4) AND (F_S  =4 ) AND ( M_S  = 4) 
THEN 'Champions'
WHEN (R_S BETWEEN 3 AND 4) AND (F_S BETWEEN 3 AND 4 ) AND ( M_S BETWEEN 2 AND 4) 
THEN 'Loyal Customers'
WHEN (R_S BETWEEN 3 AND 4) AND (F_S BETWEEN 1 AND 4) AND ( M_S BETWEEN 1 AND 4) 
THEN 'Potential Loyalists'
WHEN (R_S = 4) AND (F_S =1 ) AND ( M_S =1) 
THEN 'New Customers'
WHEN (R_S = 3) AND (F_S BETWEEN 1 AND 3) AND ( M_S BETWEEN 1 AND 3) 
THEN 'Promising'
WHEN (R_S BETWEEN 2 AND 3) AND (F_S BETWEEN 1 AND 4 ) AND ( M_S BETWEEN 1 AND 4) 
THEN 'Need Attention'
WHEN (R_S=2) AND (F_S =1 ) AND ( M_S =2) 
THEN 'About to sleep'
WHEN (R_S <=2) AND (F_S BETWEEN 1 AND 4 ) AND ( M_S BETWEEN 1 AND 4 ) 
THEN 'At risk'
WHEN (R_S <=2) AND (F_S BETWEEN 3 AND 4) AND ( M_S BETWEEN 2 AND 4) 
THEN 'Cannot lose them '
WHEN (R_S =1) AND (F_S =4 ) AND ( M_S  =1) 
THEN 'Hibernating'
WHEN (R_S =1) AND (F_S =1 ) AND ( M_S =1) 
THEN 'Lost'
END AS rfm_segment
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the database system you are using, the table structure, sample input data, the expected output, and your problems with the second part of that query

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect the code to look like this:

```
WITH rfm_raw AS (
      SELECT user_id,
             DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(),MAX(created_at), DAY) AS R,
             COUNT(*) AS F,
             AVG(SUM) AS M
      FROM `TABLE`
      GROUP BY user_id
     ),
     calc_rfm AS (
      SELECT r.*,
             NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY R ASC) as R_S,
             NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY F DESC) as F_S,
             NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY M DESC) as M_S
      FROM rfm_raw r
     )
SELECT rfm.*,
       (CASE WHEN R_S = 4 AND F_S = 4 AND M_S  = 4
             THEN 'Champions'
             WHEN R_S >= 3 AND F_S >= 3 AND M_S >= 2
             THEN 'Loyal Customers'
        END) as rfm_segment
FROM calc_rfm rfm;
```

To be honest, though, I would not use a giant `CASE` expression.  The logic in the `CASE` can be hard to follow.  You only have 64 rows, so I would put them in a table or hard code them:

```
SELECT *
FROM calc_rm rfm JOIN
     (SELECT 4 as r_s, 4 as f_s, 4 as m_s, 'Champions' as rfm_segment UNION ALL
      SELECT 4 as r_s, 4 as f_s, 3 as m_s, 'Loyalists' as rfm_segment UNION ALL
      . . . 
     ) rfm_segment
     USING (r_s, f_s, m_s)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not very good at it.
I understand the logic, but I can't fix the error.

If you have some time, could you explain in more detail ? 

At the moment I have an error:
`code` Syntax error: Expected ")" but got identifier "NTILE" at [11:14]
In the code you cited.

Comment: @Wilcat I added a missing comma and removed an unnecessary parenthesis generating the error